# Subscribing to Podcasts in Windows Media Player

Tags: windows-media-player, podcasts

I'm trying to subscribe to a podcast in Windows Media Player 10, but I did not find any options to do that. If Windows Media Player does not provide that option please suggest any other players (iTunes on Windows sucks).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It isn't possible.  Media player doesn't support podcasts.  Get the [Zune](http://www.zune.net) player instead.  It has great podcast support.  You don't need a Zune to use it either.

Comment: I wish I could up voted this answer million times.. Zune player awesome!!!

Comment: Apparently Microsoft has cancelled support for the Zune player.

Answer (score 2):

[image: iTunes]

I use [iTunes](http://www.apple.com/itunes/overview/) personally, works well on Windows and OS X.

---

I know you stated that you dislike iTunes on Windows, but I like it, regardless of platform.

You should just give it a go, especially if you have not used it recently. iTunes for Windows has really been polished up to make it harder, better, faster, stronger.

iTunes also has a massive repository of [Podcasts](http://www.apple.com/itunes/podcasts/) in it's iTunes Online Music Store. I suggest you give it a look.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I use [**Juice**](http://juicereceiver.sourceforge.net/) personally, works well on Windows and other platforms. FOSS.